# bash: Create a list of files that exist and not exist from config

Tags: bash

How can I create two variables from a source where included files do or do not exist?

As an example, in Apache configuration, files can be included but it is possible that the files do not exist.

Apache `httpd.conf` snippet:

```
Include /var/site/conf/apache/1.conf
Include /var/site/conf/apache/2.conf
Include /var/site/conf/apache/3.conf
Include /var/site/conf/apache/4.conf
```

In the include example above, `/var/site/conf/apache/4.conf` does not exist.

In auditing the Apache config, how can I list the includes that do not exist and continue to process the config files that does?

So far I've got the code below but I'm missing something that would make this work:

```sh
_Apache_includes=$(cat /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf | grep unique_site_config | cut -f 2 -d " ")
if test -f "$_Apache_includes"; then
    $_Apache_includes=$_Apache_does_exist
else
    $_Apache_includes=$_Apache_not_existing
fi
echo "$_Apache_does_exist exist"
echo "$_Apache_not_existing does not exist"

for _Config_file_check in $_Apache_includes; do
    _Config_domains=$(ls -la $_Apache_does_exist | grep -e ServerName -e ServerAlias | grep -v "#" | sed "s/^[ \t]*//" | cut -f 2 -d " " | grep -v ^$ | sort -u )
    _Config_ip=$(getent hosts $_Config_domains | awk '{ print $1 }')
    echo "Config File: $_Config_file" - $_Config_domains - $_Config_ip >> /root/server-fixes/audit/domains/domain_list_$_date_now.txt
    echo
done
```

Expected output:

File list of missing Includes:

/var/site/conf/apache/4.conf

List of correctly configured domains:

Config File: /var/unique_site_config/conf/apache/1.conf - example.com - 93.184.216.34

Config File: /var/unique_site_config/conf/apache/1.conf - www.example.com - 93.184.216.34

Config File: /var/unique_site_config/conf/apache/2.conf - example2.com - 173.231.210.103

Config File: /var/unique_site_config/conf/apache/3.conf - example3.com - 23.20.239.12

Comment: `apachectl configtest` is not what you are searching for? `continue to process the config files that does?` - what does "process" mean? How do you process it?

Comment: @KamilCuk I am auditing the configs for the sysadmins. I want to pickup up configuration issues. apachectl configtest does not complain about the missing configs.

Comment: You can replace all this `$(cat /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf | grep unique_site_config | cut -f 2 -d " ")` with just `$(awk '/unique_site_config/{print $2}' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`.

Comment: `ls -la $_Apache_does_exist | grep -e ServerName` - you meant `grep -e ServerName $_Apache_does_exists`? You script has many errors and bugs to come. Check it on http://shellcheck.net/ before posting here. How is the script related to your question? You want to list includes, yet your script check for ServerName and unique_site_config. Why is there no `grep Include` in your script if you are interested in includes?

Comment: Please post example output you are expecting. Ex. for the input you presented, the 4 lines with Include, you want just to print something like `/var/site/conf/apache/4.conf does not exists` right?

Comment: 1. grep Include in my example is substituted with grep unique_site_config because so many other things get Included too that I won't be able to programmatically differentiate between including a site config or module config.


I'm hoping in showing what I've done, I can be told where I went wrong.

Comment: Please post the content of the input files that are needed to generate the `List of correctly configured domains`. Please create an [MCVE].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this test file

```
$ cat file
    Include 1.conf
    Include 2.conf
    Include 3.conf
    Include 4.conf
```

That'll show which config exist and which isn't

```
confs=$(grep Include file) # get confs to var
confs=${confs//Include/}   # remove 'Include'
# loop through confs and check if they exist
for conf in $confs; { [[ -e $conf ]] && echo "$conf exist" || echo "$conf not exist"; }
```

And to create lists of not\exist conf

```
for conf in $confs; { [[ -e $conf ]] && exist+="$conf " || not_exist+="$conf "; }
printf "exist: $exist\nnot_exist: $not_exist"
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I was able to use it with slight modification to do exactly what I wanted. Kudos on understanding my question!

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
exists=""
missing=""
for f in $(grep httpd.conf -e ^Include | sed 's|[^/]*\(/.*\)|\1|g')
do
  if [ -e "$f" ]; then
    exists="$f\n$exists"
  else 
    missing="$f\n$missing"
  fi
done

echo "Files that are missing:"
echo -e "$missing"
```

Output:

```
Files that are missing:
/private/etc/apache2/other/*.conf
/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-manual.conf
/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf
/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-languages.conf
/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf
/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-mpm.conf
```

The `grep` matches lines where "Include" is the first word.

The `sed` matches a string starting with the first "\" in the line up to the end of the string.

`echo -e` ensures that `\n` will be interpreted as newline

Comment: the two variables are there: $exists, which contains the files that exists and $missing, which contains the files that are missing

Comment: @DaniedeJager you can't upvote, but you should be able to accept the answer, shouldn't you? If not, then excuse me.

Answer (score -1):

You need to process the files you want to test line by line and individually.

```
ls -1 |\
while IFS='\n' read -r file;
do if [ -f "${file}" ];
  then # process the ${file} or write to a tempfile
  else echo "${file} does not exist";
fi; done
```

Comment: 1. `exists` is assigned in a subshell, so it will not exists outside of it. 2. `"\n"` is not a newline. 3. [Why not to parse ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead) 4. `read file` will make the check fail if file has leading or trailing spaces in the filename or if it has any \ slashes in name.

Comment: Points 1 and 2 still stand. You can't do `echo 123 | while read file; do exists="$file"; done; echo $exists` - the variable `exists` will be empty, `echo $exists` will print an empty line. The `|` is run in a subshell. With `IFS='\n'` you will remove leading and trailing newlines in the filenames. [How to read a stream line by line](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001). The `"\n"` will be parsed to just `n`.

Comment: @KamilCuk I think OP only wants to process the files that exist, not store them in a new list, if he does not, he can save it to a file just as well. `ls -1` is there just as an example, I'm not going to copy all of OP's code. I modified the while read loop, now only filenames with newlines will fail.

Comment: @KamilCuk I just did `seq 10 | while read line; do test="${test} ${line}"; done; echo "${test}"` on a fresh shell. And I also did `echo " test " | while IFS='\n' read -r line; do echo ">${line}<"; done;` both produced the desired result.

Comment: That's strange. [repl test](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/FarReliableTrust). The first code snippet prints empty line for me.

Comment: @KamilCuk That is strange indeed... maybe something to do with interactive/non-interactive sessions? In any case I don't know what a good solution would be in that case other than directly process the result or writing to a temp file.